# How to change the color channel of the OpenCV input frame to fit the model?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing

I am still new to deep learning. So, I am trying to run OpenCV to capture frames and pass those frames to my trained model. The input required for the model has dimensions of (48,48,1).

The first layer in the model:

```
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(48,48,1),filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
```

I am trying to convert the OpenCV frame input to fit the dimensions of the model. However, I tried to use `cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` and resize but the output dimension is (48,48) only

I have tried another method shown below but the output was (48,48,3) and then after adding the axis to be able to pass it to the model the output dimension was (1,48,48,3)

```
coverted_image= cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces_detected = face_haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(coverted_image)

#Draw Triangles around the faces detected
for (x,y,w,h) in faces_detected:
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0))
    roi_gray=frame[y:y+w,x:x+h]
    roi_gray=cv2.resize(roi_gray,(48,48))
    
    image_pixels = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(roi_gray)
    print(image_pixels.shape)
    image_pixels = np.expand_dims(image_pixels, axis = 0)
    print(image_pixels.shape)
    image_pixels /= 255
    print(image_pixels.shape)
```

How can I adjust the shape of the input to (48,48,1) to be able to get the prediction from the model?

Comment: not sure what you are doing... the face_haar_cascade isnt a deep neural network but a cascade classifier detector (which uses grayscale input). If you want to use a neural network, you will use any framework like keras or tensorflow or opencv_dnn. In the documentation of that framework you will see what kind of data format they use. Typically DNNs use multi-channel input as a "blob" that means the channels are separated. In opencv you can use the blobFromImage function to prepare for opencv_dnn and probably many other frameworks.

Comment: @Micka I'm using a CNN model that I have done using Tensorflow and I'm importing it before this section of code by those statements that is what I found online `model = model_from_json(open("model.json", "r").read())
model.load_weights('model.h5')
face_haar_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openCV images are just numpy arrays, so they can be manipulated easily using numpy commands.

E.g.:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(range(48*48)).reshape(48,48)

x.shape
```

> (48, 48)

```
x = x.reshape(48,48,1)

x.shape
```

> (48, 48, 1)

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is the following:

**Detect face**

First you must detect and cut out the face section, using face_haar_cascade as you did. This gives you a data set of size (n,x,y,c,m) where n corresponds to the number of detected faces, x,y are the pixel coordinates, "C" is the number of image channels, in this case 3 (rgb format) and m is a vector of size nx1 that contains the class to which the face belongs.

**Face embbeding using FaceNet in Keras**

FaceNet is a system that, given an image of a face, extracts high-quality features from the face and predicts a 128-element vector representation of these features, called a face embedding. If you only want 48 features I recommend using a feature selection algorithm such as relief. After applying this, you will get an array of dimensions (n,128,m), n is the number of persons to classify, 128 the number of features (reducible to 48) and m refers to the class vector to which the face belongs. Assuming you have 48 images your array would be of size (48,48,1). Following this you must apply a pre-processing step such as normalizing the data and removing outliers.After that you can apply any model.

The way I did the face embedding is as follows:

```
# calculate a face embedding for each face in the dataset using facenet
from numpy import load
from numpy import expand_dims
from numpy import asarray
from numpy import savez_compressed
from keras.models import load_model

# get the face embedding for one face
def get_embedding(model, face_pixels):
    # scale pixel values
    face_pixels = face_pixels.astype('float32')
    # standardize pixel values across channels (global)
    mean, std = face_pixels.mean(), face_pixels.std()
    face_pixels = (face_pixels - mean) / std
    # transform face into one sample
    samples = expand_dims(face_pixels, axis=0)
    # make prediction to get embedding
    yhat = model.predict(samples)
    return yhat[0]


# load model
model=load_model("/<path to the folder where the model is>/facenet_keras.h5")
# load the face dataset
data = load('/<path to the folder where the dataset of detected and cropped faces is stored>/FacesDetected.npz')
trainX,trainy = data['arr_0'], data['arr_1']


# convert each face in the train set to an embedding
newTrainX = list()
for face_pixels in trainX:
    embedding = get_embedding(model, face_pixels)
    
    newTrainX.append(embedding)
newTrainX = asarray(newTrainX)

# save arrays to one file in compressed format
savez_compressed('<path to the folder where you want to save the face embeddings>/FacesEmbeddings.npz', newTrainX, trainy)
```

I recommend you to take a look at this post: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-face-recognition-system-using-facenet-in-keras-and-an-svm-classifier/